# How to add created in runtime properties file to classpath

Tags: java, properties, runtime, classpath

I have a process that create properties file with texts and copy it into folder with other properties file, i'm looking for a way to add the new file into class path in order to use it without restarting my server every time i create new properties file. I tried to following code but it doesn't work.

```
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = cl.getResource(resourceName);
        if(url == null) {
            URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            Class sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;
            URL fileUrl = new URL(resourceName);
            Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", fileUrl.getClass());
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(sysloader, new Object[]{fileUrl});
        }
    } catch (Exception ignore) { }

    return url;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using spring in your application?

Comment: Try creating your own ClassLoader. If the files you generate are located in a specific package, you could create your own loader to scan and load the files as required at runtime.

Comment: @ShishirKumar no, i'm not using spring

Comment: Are you getting any error? I see your catch block is swallowing every error. Can you post your error stacktrace.

Comment: @ShishirKumar i don't get any error, the method cl.getResource(resourceName) returns null. I already checked it